# Oracle function to_char(date, "IW") in .net

Tags: .net, oracle, datetime

What is the .net equivalent of the Oracle to_char(date, "IW") function (returns the week number). I tried using CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday) but some results don't match. Not really sure what values I should pass for the CalendarWeekRule and DayOfWeek enums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Oracle uses the ISO-8601 definition of "week of year" which isn't *quite* supported by .NET out of the box. However, [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnste/archive/2006/01/24/iso-8601-week-of-year-format-in-microsoft-net.aspx) gives some alternative code you could use to fudge it.

As an aside, I'd be interested to know whether my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) project gives you the right results (you could always use that instead of `DateTime` :) - if you can give some sample input, Oracle output and .NET output (particularly where they differ) that would be useful to me.

Comment: Thanks Jon.

My data set contained 2191 days (The days from 2006 to the end of 2011). 

I used the function TO_CHAR( date ,'IW') in Oracle and 
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(from, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday) in .Net.

Here is a link to the rows that did not match: http://notepad.cc/share/U6ZetqDI6N.

These include the 8th of January 2008 for example, oracle outputs a value of 2 whereas .net, with the given arguments, outputs 1.

Comment: @Fikre: Thanks very much for that - I've validated the end/start of the year for those dates in Noda Time, and they all match Oracle: http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/diff?spec=svn6f2df473f00c8b70be1239251c5e6a9a1ab8a07b&r=6f2df473f00c8b70be1239251c5e6a9a1ab8a07b&format=side&path=/src/NodaTime.Test/LocalDateTest.BasicProperties.cs